# How do I set the WebKit version used by a WebView...?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, webkit, linkage

I'm using WebKit in an OS X app via the [JUCE WebBrowserComponent](https://www.juce.com/doc/classWebBrowserComponent), a lightweight wrapper around Apple's `WebView` Objective-C class.
 I'm compiling on OS X 10.12 with a deployment target of 10.7.

The issue I'm having is that on OS X 10.8, the version of WebKit used by the `WebView` seems to be different to that used by Safari and I can't figure out how the WebKit version is selected or *why* they are different.

Running `otool -L` on Safari, gives me:

```
otool -L /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Safari | grep WebKit
    /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 536.30.1)
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/Versions/A/WebKit2 (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 536.30.1)
```

Running `otool -L` on the Juce demo gives me:

```
otool -L JuceDemo | grep WebKit
    /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 602.2.14)
```

**Firstly, why are the "current version" numbers different, for apparently the same linked framework?**

Also, if I point the respective applications at http://browserspy.dk/webkit.php It gives me a AppleWebKit version of **600.8.9** for Safari and a version of **536.30.1** for JUCE Demo.

**What accounts for these different version numbers, and how can I configure my application so that my `WebView` uses the "600.8.9" version of WebKit used by Safari?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### otool version

The *current version* that *otool* outputs is the version that was used to link when the app was build.

### Safari, WebKit and everything

On the latest macOS release Safari uses the system WebKit version. So macOS Sierra 10.12 with Safari 10 uses */System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit*.

Safari also supports older macOS releases. And is updated independently from the system. For example Safari 10 runs on macOS 10.10, 10.11 and 10.12. Now macOS 10.11 was released with Safari 9, but when Safari 10 is installed it uses not the system WebKit. Instead a version in  */System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari* is used.

**Why?**

New major Safari versions not only add shiny new features, and bugs, they sometimes also remove things. Some ill faded -webkit prefixes come to mind. WebKit is part of the SDK which *guaranties* you that your app will not break on such updates.

### Testing

Here the version output of a test app from WebView and WKWebView:

**macOS 10.8.5** (12F2560):

> Safari Version 6.2.8 (8537.85.17.9.1)
>   WebKit Version **600.8.9**
>
> Cocoa App
>   WebView WebKit Version **536.30.1**

**macOS 10.9.5** (13F1911):

> Safari Version 9.1.3 (9537.86.7.8) 
>   WebKit Version **601.7.8**
>
> Cocoa App 
>   WebView WebKit Version **537.78.2**

**macOS 10.10.5** (14F2009):

> Safari Version 10.0.1 (10602.2.14.0.7) 
>   WebKit Version **602.2.14**
>
> Cocoa App  
>   WebView WebKit Version **600.8.9**  
>   WKWebView WebKit Version **600.8.9**

**macOS 10.11.6** (15G1108):

> Safari Version 10.0.1 (11602.2.14.0.7) 
>  WebKit
>   Version **602.2.14**
>
> Cocoa App  
>   WebView WebKit Version **601.7.8**  
>   WKWebView WebKit Version **601.7.8**

### Answer

It is not supported to link your app to the Safari WebKit version.

You could include your own WebKit build. But I think it's simpler to write your web code for the old version of your deployment target.

Comment: Thanks. re: "As far as I know you cannot link your app to the Safari WebKit version" — unless Safari is statically linking to WebKit (which I doubt), then this can't be true, can it? Presumably the version in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks` is the one supplying Safari with the updated functionality? As an experiment I tried pointing my app at that with `install_name_tool`, but I get `dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_WebView`. So, I guess the fact Safari links to both versions is somehow significant. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Honest I was surprised myself when I looked into it. I expected Safari to include it's own version of WebKit - like the Safari Technology Preview.

But this doesn't change anything: The SDK provides you with WebView and WKWebView with a specific WebKit version. Not always the latest and greatest Safari WebKit version.

Comment: OK, I've marked this as accepted, because I think you're right, what I'm asking in my question isn't possible, or at least it isn't supported.

Comment: If I figure out how this is done I let you know. Your deployment target seems super old, well, I only drop 10.8 three month ago so I know how this goes. Maybe rethinking that makes the webkit version less of an issue.

Comment: Thanks and yeah. We don't *currently* support 10.8, but we have users requesting it and this is the showstopper

Comment: Assuming I did want to include my own WebKit build, how would I do that? Is it just a case of downloading a nightly build, linking to the included frameworks and bundling them with my app?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, so I don't know. But you are trying to get new WebKit version working on an old macOS so I'm sure it would be significant amount of work.

Comment: @JamieBullock not sure how I overlooked it the first time but I found it: /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari.

Comment: Both WebView and WKWebview on macOS 10.13.4 gives WebKit 605.1.15. I don’t have macOS 10.12 with me.

Comment: `Assuming I did want to include my own WebKit build, how would I do that?` - OLD thread, but I have a hunch you can't. AFAIK Apple's WebKit `port` uses ObjC and newer versions are bound to use newer ObjC features that requirer newer versions of the Mac OS. (Incidentally, THE big reason why ObjC will sadly not see more widespread use outside the Apple universe, IMHO.)